# How to set the json in right format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

View Model

```
function CustInfo() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.CustInfo = {
        "custId": "",
        "custTitle": "",
        "custName": ""
    };

    return vm;
}
```

Global Values

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var obj = null;

angular
   .module('app')
   .value('Cust_Info', new CustInfo());

 })();
```

Angular Controller

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("custCtrl", custCtrl);

custCtrl.$inject = ['dataService','Cust_Info'];

/* @ngInject */
function custCtrl(dataService, Cust_Info) {
    var vm = this;

    function _GetData() {

        //scar
        dataService.read(id).then(function (data) {
            if (data.fields != null) {
                //set meta data
                Cust_Info.custId = data.fields.id;
                Cust_Info.custNumber = data.fields.number;
                //store into session storage
                sessionStorage.info = JSON.stringify(cust_Info);
            }
        });


    }


    return vm;
}
})();
```

But when service is called & I check sessionStorage the custInfo looks as below.

```
{
"CustInfo": {
    "custId": "",
    "custTitle": "",
    "custNumber": ""
},
"custId": "1",
"custNumber": "021758"
}
```

While I am trying to set the json as below

```
{
"CustInfo": {
    "custId": "1",
    "custNumber": "021758"
    "custTitle": "",
 }
}
```

> What is causing this?

***Also I was wondering if somehow without storing it in the session storage, if I could to access CustInfo updated values into different controller since I have declared it as global values.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Part of the solution**:

You are not returning the correct object

```
function CustInfo() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.CustInfo = {
        "custId": "",
        "custTitle": "",
        "custName": ""
    };

    return vm.CustInfo ;
}
```

**Second Part of the solution**

You can access `Cust_Info` across your application if you define it as a constant. You can then inject this to any *controller, config, or service*.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var obj = null;

angular
   .module('app')
   .constant('Cust_Info', 
    return new CustInfo());

 })();
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will mark this ans as accepted once it allows. Meanwhile, can you please share your insight on the second part of the question (bottom in bold italic)

Comment: But they're not constant. Can't I access it in the same fashion of constant but using .value()

Comment: Even if they are declared as constants, it will be available across the application and you can update the value and the updated value will be avaiable

Comment: Ok. Thanks Can you please upvote the post if you find it worth?

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)

Comment: I think value will also suffice as part of the second question you asked. Check if updated value is present in another controller. But everytime you are creating a new object, try to return the updated object

Comment: I will check & I think it will be accessible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding extra `CustInfo` attribute to your `CustInfo object`.

Try below code,

```
function CustInfo() {
        var vm = this;

        vm = {
            "custId": "",
            "custTitle": "",
            "custName": ""
        };

        return vm;
    }
```